# How to customize the question label used by \Question in the exercise package

Tags: exercises

How can I customize the question label used by `\Question` in the `exercise` package?

I'm using the `exercise` package. I want to customize it such that the enumeration generated by `\Question` uses letters ((a), (b), ...) rather than numbers (1. 2. ...).

In particular, this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noanswer]{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\Question qwer
\Question asdf
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

produces the output
[image: output of exercise]

I would like to have

```
(a) qwer
(b) asdf
```

I suspect that setting `QuestionHeaderNB` will do the trick, but I haven't found how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find anything related to that type of customisation in the `exercise` package documentation, but the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noanswer]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{(\alph{Question})\ }

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\Question qwer
\Question asdf
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]